# Date greater than the current time in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm having to move a project from rails to angular, Much to my disgrace.

How would i go about changing this

`<% if souporder.datefrom > Time.now %>`

into angular terms?

heres my code

```
<tr ng-repeat="soup in souporders">
               <td>{{soup.id}}</td>
               <td>{{soup.soup}}</td>
               <td>{{soup.datefrom}}</td>
               <td>{{soup.dateto}}</td>
             </tr>
```

**Edit**
This is in my view

```
         <div ng-repeat="soup in souporders">
         <tr ng-if="date == soup.datefrom">
```

And this is in my controller

```
$scope.date = new Date();
```

Comment: Do you expect it to update the view as soon as the current time passes the datefrom? You're going to need an event, I think. This isn't Angular's strong point but of course it's doable.

Comment: Only wanted it to be done on the page refresh, Like rails does, Its a date not minutes, Should have made that clear!

Comment: Also, why "much to my disgrace"? Angular is a great framework, but even if you think it isn't, you'll probably get a better answer from angular experts if you don't insult the framework in your question :)

Answer (score 1):

You clarified in the comments that you only need this calculated on page refresh, which is pretty simple and doesn't require much angular magic.

On initializing the view's controller, simply set a variable whether or not the order date is in the future or not and expose it on the scope. Then bind directly to it, and use the bindonce functionality `{{:myvariable}}` to improve performance because it won't be changing anyway.

Depending on your needs, you can even have the server calculate that value and return it as a property of each order in your JSON array of orders. (I'm guessing a bit at what you're doing, but you can adapt the answer if you're not doing what I think you're doing.)

**Update**: I just realized that perhaps your objective is not to do something special with each row based on the date, but to filter the list based on the date. Most of my answer still stands, but you can forget about the bindonce spiel. What you need is called an angular filter on `ng-repeat` and is done using the pipe (|) character. You can read all about it by searching the topic. There are examples in the angularjs docs. But basically, instead of:

```
<tr ng-repeat="soup in souporders">
    <td>{{soup.id}}</td>
    <td>{{soup.soup}}</td>
    <td>{{soup.datefrom}}</td>
    <td>{{soup.dateto}}</td>
    <td>{{:soup.active}}</>  <!--do something nice here instead of just displaying true/false --->
</tr>
```

You might want:

```
<tr ng-repeat="soup in souporders | filter:{current: true}">
    ...etc
</tr>
```

Either on the server or on the client, when you load the data from the server, you can add a boolean property to the items in the souporders array that says whether it's current or not.

**What this accomplishes:**

You have a filtered list of items based on a property that does NOT change dynamically and requires a page reload to update. But it's fast (but not the fastest it could be if you really need to go crazy - don't prematurely optimize, you'll know what to do when the time comes to do it, and that time isn't now).

**Why it's not that great:**

It isn't dynamic and it isn't angular-y or declarative. But based on your requirements, it's a solution. I'd spend some time considering if you want this to be dynamic, and if not, why the items that aren't showing are even returned from the server. Are they used elsewhere on the page?

Comment: Which part? The view? controller?

Comment: Let me add some more code to what i've done one min :)